# How does Kakutani's theorem imply consistency of the likelihood ratio estimator?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, martingales

I am currently trying to understand how consistency of the likelihood ratio estimator follows from [Kakutani's theorem](http://www.ressources-actuarielles.net/EXT/ISFA/1226.nsf/0/6021110392b6ba43c1256f6a002d5f33/$FILE/AP3.pdf):

**Kakutani's theorem**
Let $(X_n)_{n\ge1}$ be a sequence of independent non-negative random variables of mean $1$.
Set $a_n:=E(\sqrt{X_n})\in(0,1]$ and define $M_0:=1,\,M_{n\ge 1}:=\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i$. Then $(M_n)_{n\ge 0}$ is a non-negative martingale and $M_n\to M_{\infty}$ a.s. for some random variable $M_\infty$. Moreover,

(a) if $\prod_n a_n>0,$ then $M_n\to M_{\infty}$ in $L^1$ and $E(M_{\infty})=1,$
(b) if $\prod_n a_n=0,$ then $M_{\infty}=0$ a.s.

**Corollary**
Let $P$ and $\tilde{P}$ be probability measures on a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$. Let $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of random variables. Assume that, under $P$ (respectively $\tilde{P}$), the random variables $X_n$ are independent and $X_n$ has law $\mu_n$ (respectively $\tilde{\mu}_n$) for all $n$.
Suppose that $\tilde{\mu}_n=f_n\mu_n$ for all $n$.
Define the likelihood ratio $L_n:=\prod_{i=1}^{n}f_n(X_n)$. Then, under $P$,

(a) if $\prod_n \int_{\mathbb{R}}\sqrt{f_n}d\mu_n>0$, then $L_n$ converges a.s. and in $L^1$,
(b) if $\prod_n \int_{\mathbb{R}}\sqrt{f_n}d\mu_n=0$, then $L_n\to 0$ a.s.

**In particular, if $\mu_n=\mu$ and $\tilde{\mu}_n=\tilde{\mu}$ for all $n$ with $\mu\neq \tilde{\mu}$, then $P(L_n\to 0)=1,\ \tilde{P}(L_n\to\infty)=1$.**

---

Since $f_n(X_n)$ is a random variable with mean $1$ under $P$, I can understand that $P(L_n\to 0)=1$ in the corollary. However, where does $\tilde{P}(L_n\to\infty)=1$ come from?

Furthermore, I have read that this implies consistency of the likelihood ratio statistic  $L_n$ but for this we would have to fix real parameters for $\mu$ and $\tilde{\mu}$. From the corollary, the obvious and only possible choices for $\mu$ and $\tilde{\mu}$ would be $0$ and $\infty$, respectively. The problem here is that $\infty\not\in\mathbb{R}$, or am I missing something e.g. that $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ is allowed as parameter?

Comment: To say anything about $\tilde{P},$ we'd need an analogous statement to $(a), (b)$ under $\tilde{P}$. This is actually quickly forthcoming - assume for now that $f_n \neq 0$. Then, in analogy, define $g_n = 1/f_n$ and the process $M_n = 1/L_n$. By the same idea, if $ \prod\int \sqrt{g_n} \mathrm{d}\tilde{\mu}  \to 0 \iff \prod \int \sqrt{f_n} \mathrm{d}\mu \to 0$ then under $\tilde{P},$ $M_n \to 0$ a.s., but this (and $M_n \ge 0$) implies that $L_n \to \infty$ a.s.

Comment: Now you need to do some book-keeping to show that the same thing happens when $f_n$ may be $0$ (the idea is just that you're assuming samples from $\tilde{P}$ anyway, and $\tilde{P}( x: f_n(x) = 0) = 0,$ so you can get away with things). Also the consistency is in the sense of consistency for hypothesis testing - take the null hypothesis that the data comes from $P$. Under $\tilde{P}$ the statistic grows arbitrarily large, and thus any test that rejects the null for large values of $L_n$ will asymptotically have power $1$. I don't see where parameters enter the picture.